# What is the job table for in Airflow metadata?

Tags: airflow

I see that we have the `job` table in the Airflow metadata database. I'd like to understand what the rows in that table mean.
I have this doubt because when we have some failure in a task, the `task_instance` table rows are being set as failed, but the jobs in the `job` table continue with `running` state indefinitely.
So, I'd like to know what those jobs represent and if it's ok to have those instances left as `running` forever. I mean, don't they impact in scheduler parallelism or such things?

Comment: The scheduler uses the job table to store data about scheduling. Also, it should contain failed jobs.

Comment: @Honarkhah, could you please give more information on this, perhaps in its own Answer?

Comment: @cdabel if you ask what you want to know about it I can give you more context.